# addObject happening multiple times identically?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I am super new to xcode/iOS dev. I wrote a tutorial app in objective c and it worked like a charm. My next attempt was to rewrite it in swift.

Something very strange is happening. The "objects" NSMutableArray gets filled up w/identical items every time it finds a node in the xml doc. (instead of appending). I tried making objects simply: var objects = NSMutableArray() and then using objects.addObject(currentFacility) but same thing happend.

The Log paste is basically first logging in that parser entered company node. Then in a for loop it prints out index and contents of objects array that the company got added to.

I tried to cut out unrelated code. But I am not sure what is the cause, thus the verbosity.

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController, NSXMLParserDelegate {
    var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
    var objects = [Facility]()
    var currentFacility = Facility()
    var currentValue = ""
    var counter = 0

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
        currentValue = ""
        if(elementName == "Facility") {
            counter += 1
            NSLog("LOG: entered co \(counter) \n")
        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didEndElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI:         String!, qualifiedName qName: String!) {
      //[Code here that correctly catches sub nodes omitted for brevity]
      // finished parsing job - add it to the array
        if(elementName == "Facility") {
            objects.append(currentFacility)

            //var desc = currentFacility.description()
            for index in 0...(self.objects.count - 1) {
                var obPrint = self.objects[index] as Facility
                var desc2 = obPrint.description()
                NSLog("\(desc2) and index is \(index)")
            }
            NSLog("LOG: exited co \(counter) \n")
        }
    }
}
```

Log Paste below that contains print out of the OBJECTS array, some removed for readability:

> parser in DID START document 
>  LOG: entered co 1 
>  ECO
>   FINISHING 5100 INDUSTRIAL BLVD  FRIDLEY and index is 0 
>  LOG:
>   exited co 1 
>  LOG: entered co 2 
>  ADVANCED FLEX INC. PLANT 2
>   3905 CALIFORNIA ST. N.E.  COLUMBIA HEIGHTS and index is 0 
>   ADVANCED FLEX INC. PLANT 2 3905 CALIFORNIA ST. N.E.  COLUMBIA HEIGHTS
>   and index is 1 
>  LOG: exited co 2 
>  LOG: entered co 3 
>  H.
>   B. FULLER CO. MONARCH DIV. 3900 JACKSON ST. N.E.  COLUMBIA HEIGHTS and
>   index is 0 
>  H. B. FULLER CO. MONARCH DIV. 3900 JACKSON ST. N.E. 
>   COLUMBIA HEIGHTS and index is 1 
>  H. B. FULLER CO. MONARCH DIV.
>   3900 JACKSON ST. N.E.  COLUMBIA HEIGHTS and index is 2 
>  LOG:
>   exited co 3 
>  more of the same, cut for brevity.
>  .
>   .
>
> LOG: exited co 10 
>  LOG: entered co 11 
>  ATLAS MFG. 5250 INDL.
>   BLVD. N.E.  FRIDLEY and index is 0 
>  ATLAS MFG. 5250 INDL. BLVD.
>   N.E.  FRIDLEY and index is 1 
>  ATLAS MFG. 5250 INDL. BLVD. N.E. 
>   FRIDLEY and index is 2 
>  ATLAS MFG. 5250 INDL. BLVD. N.E.  FRIDLEY
>   and index is 3 
>  ATLAS MFG. 5250 INDL. BLVD. N.E.  FRIDLEY and
>   index is 4 
>  ATLAS MFG. 5250 INDL. BLVD. N.E.  FRIDLEY and index
>   is 5
>  ATLAS MFG. 5250 INDL. BLVD. N.E.  FRIDLEY and index is
>   6
>  ATLAS MFG. 5250 INDL. BLVD. N.E.  FRIDLEY and index is 7
>   ATLAS MFG. 5250 INDL. BLVD. N.E.  FRIDLEY and index is 8
>  ATLAS
>   MFG. 5250 INDL. BLVD. N.E.  FRIDLEY and index is 9
>  ATLAS MFG.
>   5250 INDL. BLVD. N.E.  FRIDLEY and index is 11
>  LOG: exited co 11
>   
>   parser in DID End document

Comment: Please remove any code not necessary for reproducing the error. You can see the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information

Comment: done. What is happening? Why is it acting this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`currentFacility` is declared as a property of the class itself and is only assigned to once (with its default value). Also, `Facility` is a [reference type](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_143) so each time you append it to the array, it is appending a **reference** to the same instance.

When you update the properties of `currentFacility` you are updating all the ones you appended to the array because they are all still referencing the same thing.

If you want to start working with a new `currentFacility`, you should create a new instance after finding each node or after appending to the array:

```
self.currentFacility = Facility()
```